# Pandas - Issue with plotting a graph after group by

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am have a table "attendance" in sqlite3 which I am importing as a dataframe using pandas. The dataframe looks like this,

```
      id    name       date                time
0  12345  Pankaj 2020-09-12 1900-01-01 23:17:49
1  12345  Pankaj 2020-09-12 1900-01-01 23:20:28
2  12345  Pankaj 2020-09-13 1900-01-01 13:36:01
```

A person a 'id' can appear multiple times, which is equivalent to a person going in and out of the door multiple times a day and we are recording each of that transition.

I wish to find the difference of time last out and first in, to find the number of hours a person was present at the work.

Since we need only the data for one person at a time, I am first filtering out data for one person, like this .

```
df = df.loc[df['id']== id]
```

This leaves me all the entries for a particular person.

Now, for difference of the last entry time and the first entry time, I am calculating like this,

```
df_gp = df.groupby('date')['time']
difference = df_gp.max() - df_gp.min()
```

Now, the "difference" comes out as a pandas series.

```
date
2020-09-12   00:02:39
2020-09-13   00:00:00
```

When I try to plot the graph using the pandas.series.plot() method, with type kind = 'line', like this,

```
difference.plot(kind = 'line')
```

I don't see graph being made at all. I don't see any error of such, it just simply does not show anything.

When I print,

```
print(difference.plot(kind = 'line'))
```

It prints in the terminal this,

```
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.2;0.775x0.68)
```

So I thought, it must be something with time.sleep() that the graph gets destroyed and exits the function too quickly, but it is not the case, I have tried so many thing, it simply doesn't show.

I need help with-

1. I don't; know if this is the correct way to have a graph when I want to have difference of time for a particular day. Please suggest if you have any elegant way to do the same.
2. What is the reason it doesn't show at all?

---

Complete code

```
def main():
    emp_id = "12345"
    db = os.path.join(constants.BASE_DIR.format("db"),"db_all.db")
    with closing(sqlite3.connect(db)) as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from attendance where id = {} order by date ASC".format(emp_id), conn, parse_dates={'date':'%Y-%m-%d',
            'time':'%H:%M:%S'})

    print(df.head())
    #df = df.loc[df['id']== id]
    is_empty = df.empty
    if is_empty:
        messagebox.showerror("Error","There are not enough records of employee")
        return
    
    # Add the latest row
    emp_name = df.loc[(df['id'] == id).idxmax(),'name']
    # dt_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    # _date, _time = dt_time.date(),dt_time.time()


    # print(type(_date))
    # print(type(_time))
    # df.loc[-1] = [emp_id,emp_name,_date,_time]

    # df.index += 1
    # df = df.sort_index()

    # print(df.dtypes)
    df_gp = df.groupby('date')['time']
    print("Here")
    difference = df_gp.max() - df_gp.min()
    print(difference)
    print(difference.plot(kind = 'line'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

-Thanks

Comment: `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and add `plt.show()` after `plot`.

Comment: @HenryYik That was great henry. Thanks so much. It would be great if you can also help with my first request ?